# Deleting CoreData object & Inverse relationships

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship, inverse

I have an object (A) that has a To-Many relationship to another object (B).
Also, B holds an inverse relationship to A.

When I delete B, It still shown on A's relation ship count, unless i manually clean the inverse relationship of B before deletion.
I want it to happen synchronously, so i could update a UITableView and delete B's row,
instead of waiting for MOC's save action to complete.

Is there any way to handle that without manually cleaning B's inverse?
(I have tons of these relationships and it would be bad practice & hard to maintain)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That should work automatically if you set the "Delete Rule" for the inverse relationship from B to A to "Nullify" in the Core Data Model inspector in Xcode.

See [Relationship Delete Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW1) in the "Core Data Programming Guide" for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but it's already set to Nullify. I believe that it would update after the next MOC save (though deletion and accessing relationship both on main thread's MOC), Anyway +1 for the link :)

Comment: @avishic: You are right, it is indeed updated only after the save, I forgot that, sorry. - Do you use a fetched results controller for the table view? That should update even without save (I think).

Answer (score 1):

Almost 5 years later (at iOS 10 now) and I stumbled upon the same issue.

App started crashing after I decided to 'optimise' things by removing the `saveContext()` from almost everywhere, thinking that the in-memory representation is guaranteed to be correct (since `includesPendingChanges` is `true` by default).

However I was getting the issue described (and because later some `UITableView` needed to be updated, app was crashing).

Here are four separate approaches, any one of which solved the issue in my case:
(ordered from best to worst as far as I can judge)

- calling `processPendingChanges()` (on the `NSManagedObjectContext`) after the deletion
- calling `refreshAllObjects()` (on the `NSManagedObjectContext`) after the deletion
- calling `saveContext()` after the deletion (as others have pointed out in the comments)
- just waiting. for example, delaying the execution of the code that depends on the correct data by 0.1 seconds or so (using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`). (this of course is by far the worst approach and you should not implement it)

Things I am still not sure about:

- I tried replicating it on a separate very small example project and I did not get the issue. So what is the underlying problem?
- Is this expected behaviour or a bug? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: `processPendingChanges()` resolved the issue for me.